# Unable to install ubuntu-device-flash in 14.04

Tags: apt, package-management, ubuntu-touch, flash, dependencies

I have problem with this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-device-flash
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-device-flash : Depends: qemu-user-static but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

Answer (score 0):

Before installing ubuntu-device-flash you should ensure you have the universe archive enabled. From the Ubuntu help:

Additional software repositories such as Universe and Multiverse can be enabled by uncommenting the corresponding apt lines (i.e. delete the '#' at the beginning of the line). For Universe, uncomment those lines:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates universe
```

You find the apt lines in /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Don't forget to retrieve the updated package lists:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I have universe enabled and still no joy

Comment: @CarlosDunick I just tried it with a fresh Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, the universe archive was already enabled. Installation was no problem.